# What does the name “Furtwängler” mean?

Tags: person-names

Is this an occupational surname?  If so, what is a Furtwängler?

“Furt” might be a [ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_%28crossing%29), but my web searching has not found any gloss for “Wängler”.

Comment: A _Furtwängler_ is a person from [_Furtwangen_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furtwangen_im_Schwarzwald). So, no occupation. Regarding *-wangen*, it is derived from the extinct word [_Wang_](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=wang).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Vorfahren der Furtwängler kamen aus Furtwangen im Schwarzwald (BW, de). Die erste Erwähnung dieses Ortsnamens findet sich 1179 in einer Bulle von Papst Alexander III.

Furtwangen bedeutet die "Siedlung beim Weideland an der Furt". Die Furt befand sich unterhalb des Zusammentreffens von drei Tälern und Flüssen. Einer dieser Flüsse ist die Breg, der längste Quellfluss der Donau.

z. T. nach:
https://books.google.ch/books?id=olXnBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=furtwangen+furt&source=bl&ots=VTZb9uE7cc&sig=S79jOgOuHjTstwh18DkcuUyvpOs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM_-OdwuHKAhVHPQ8KHX6VBCwQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=furtwangen%20furt&f=false

Answer (score 5):

As per chirlu's comment, Furtwängler is not an occupational name.  It is a toponym, meaning a person from [Furtwangen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furtwangen_im_Schwarzwald) in southwestern Germany.